# Asp.Net MVC3 Webgrid Paging Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a Asp.Net Mvc3 webgrid below my webpage After 10 paragraphs. When I click on page number in webgrid, it pulls page to top because it shows its hyperlink as #. I do not want page to move up on clicking page number in webgrid.

```
@{ 
        var gridUser = new WebGrid(canPage: true, defaultSort: "CreatedOn", rowsPerPage: 5, 
                                ajaxUpdateContainerId: "DivGridUser"); 
        gridUserRoles.Bind(Model.User, rowCount: Model.User.Count(), autoSortAndPage: true); 
        gridUserRoles.Pager(WebGridPagerModes.All); 

        } 
        <div id="DivGridUser" style="display: none"> 
            @gridUserRoles.GetHtml(htmlAttributes: new { id = "DivGridUser" }, 
        columns: gridUser.Columns( 
        gridUserRoles.Column("Name"), 
        gridUserRoles.Column("CreatedOn") 
        ) 
    )
```

I am using AjaxUpdateContainerId to make paging ajaxified.
Can some one guide me fixing this issue.
.